# Should I use Kafka or just a load balancer?

Tags: apache-kafka, architecture, load

I am trying to create a Telegram bot. The Telegram API allows me to give it a link to my own API, and it sends "updates" (which are json-serialized update objects representing some event that has occured with regard to my bot) to that link as a POST request.
Right now I'm trying to design the infrastructure of the system and I'm torn between two designs for the part of my system that captures and processes these update POST requests:

1. I can have a simple API that catches the update data, deserializes it, and puts it in a Kafka topic. I can then have a bunch of workers try to consume the events in that Kafka topic.
2. I can just install a load balancer and connect it to some workers. The workers get the updates and respond to them in real time.

This has been a recurring problem for me: should I store events and have workers process them after retrieval, or should I just use a load balancer and direct the events to the workers in real time?
I need to know when to use each approach, and if there are alternative approaches to this problem that I have not yet thought of.

Comment: HTTP is stateless and cannot easily be replayed. Do you care if you miss a message? Then use Kafka. HTTP requests Do you need to parallelize any workloads, rather than simply distribute? Then use Kafka. Do you not want to manage external infrastructure more than your loadbalancer and HTTP server(s). Then _dont_ use Kafka... Also, why Kafka? There are other message queues that work too, e.g. SNS/SQS and Telegram would work well

Comment: If you want to persist your events and you want to decouple production and consuming of events, then use kafka. If you want a synchronous approach use the balancer. If you use a synchronous approach your workers must be able to scale properly as the load is not a known parameter (telegram updates).

Answer (score 0):

Using Kafka for your scenario helps since it provides an asynchronous and resilient way
Since Kafka has semantics like at least once and exactly once it can be quite useful to gain resiliency

Now you can prefer load balancing when you need end-to-end stateless and synchronous processing and inherently has the resilience from different mechanisms.

But one of the major design factors would be the extra infra that you would need to build for Kafka whereas you can create load balancer with the same infra